# Why do we use would + infinitive rather than past? [wish]

Tags: modal-verbs, sentence-meaning

In the sentence:

> We all wish the snow *would stay* forever.

Why can't we say

> We all wish the snow *stayed* forever.

What are differences between these sentences?

Comment: It's not "would + present". It's actually "would + infinitive". In many cases, the present and infinitive are the same, but a notable example is "would be" ("be" is the infinitive form, while the present forms are "am", "is", "are").

Comment: In American English, they're interchangeable in everyday speech.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Swan's [Practical English Usage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Practical_English_Usage), Unit 630.4, we can use past tenses in a *that-clause* after *wish*:

> I wish tomorrow *was* Sunday.

Note that here the past tense is used to refer to the future. 
If we want a sentence of this structure to refer to the past, we use past perfect tenses, according to Swan:

> I wish you *hadn't said* that.

In [Quirk's Comprehensive Grammar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Comprehensive_Grammar_of_the_English_Language), Unit 14.23 says that "in subordinate clauses following *I wish (that)*, the hypothetical past may be replaced by hypothetical *would* or by a *to-infinitive*":

> I wish she *visited* me more often.
>   I wish she *would visit* me more often.
>   I wish her *to visit* me more often.

This means we can also say:

> We all wish the snow *to stay* forever.

(Native speakers might find this sentence unnatural. It looks unnatural to me.)

I went on reading Swan further and found one interesting distinction (Unit 630.5): *Wish ... wouldn't* sentences can be used as orders or requests:

> I wish you *wouldn't drink so much*. (meaning, "Please don't drink so much".)

but:

> I wish you *didn't drink so much*. (here, the meaning is closer to "I'm sorry that you drink so much".)

So, in such negative sentences the use of the simple past gives a different shade of meaning compared with the use of the infinitive with the modal *would*.

Comment: I see that footnote in Quirk et al, but I have to admit "I wish her to visit me more often" does seem unnatural to me.

Comment: I am not a native speaker. But I found this sentence in Oxford Advanced learner's dictionary - ***He was not sure whether he wished her to stay or go.***. So from this sentence it seems that ***I wish her to visit me more often*** is correct. And hence this too seems correct - ***We all wish the snow to stay forever***. Please comment. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Man_From_India I don't think any of those three sentences is incorrect, but I wouldn't personally say any of them.

Comment: @snailboat Thanks for some input. I have checked Merriam Websters also. Yet I didn't find such example sentences. Though that doesn't mean in AmE we don't construct this way. But still, is there any possibility of AmE and BrE difference regarding this matter?

Comment: @Man_From_India It seems plausible that there's an AmE versus BrE difference, but I honestly have no idea.  You might need to do some investigation with a corpus or two to figure it out.

Comment: @snailboat Thank you very much. I will do some investigation myself, let's see if I can dig out anything significant :)

Comment: I don't understand meaning of _I wish her to visit me more often_. May you mean _I wish she to visit me more often_?

Comment: @DmitryFucintv - you might want to look up Topic 428 in Swan's Practical English Usage. It says that we use the form *her* if the pronoun is the object of a verb or preposition. In Quirk's examples 1 and 2, *she* is a subject in a that-clause: "I wish (that) *she* would visit me more often".

Comment: @DmitryFucintv We can relate this to the "**for A to B**" structure, from which *for* is often omitted.  A real example from the web, found via COCA: ["He's an animal. I don't wish ***for* him *to* die**. I wish ***for* him *to* have** a long, suffering, cruel death."](http://seattletimes.com/html/localnews/2001819213_families19m.html)  If you think about it as omission of *for*, then *her* might make more sense to you than *she*.

Comment: *"Note that here the past tense is used to refer to the future."* <== That's not quite right. The past-tense "was" is used for *modal remoteness*, due to the "wish" construction, and is not used to indicate "past time". The future time is indicated by the word "tomorrow". You can see this in the example *"I wish grandma was here"*, which means that I have the desire that grandma  be right here now in front of me--which is the present time. (cont.)

Comment: (cont.) The reason why a past-perfect construction is often used to indicate past time in a "wish" construction is that it--the perfect construction--actually has two past tenses in it, and one past tense is used for modal remoteness and the other past tense is used to indicate the "past time". The perfect construction itself is a secondary "past tense", and the past-tense verb "had" that is in a past-perfect construction is itself a primary "past tense" (vs a primary "present tense" verb "have/has").